# Styling Semantic UI elements within jQuery AJAX success function

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, semantic-ui

I'm fairly new to UI, styling, etc., but I'm trying to create a dynamic set of Semantic UI cards within an Ajax success function, and the styling of the elements doesn't appear to be working.  I can get the JSON data from the REST service just fine and that data does display on my page as expected, it's just the UI elements aren't being styled.  The other Semantic UI elements on the page are styled fine - it's just these that are inside the block aren't.

I have a `<div>` tag where I want to have the cards injected into the page, like this:

```
<div class="schedule-data"></div>
```

Here's the jQuery AJAX code I currently have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://localhost:3001/schedule",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.schedule-data').append(`<div class="ui link cards">`);
            data.map(item => {

                // Inject card markup for each schedule item here

            });
            $('.schedule-data').append(`</div>`);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            alert('Error!');
        }
    })
});
```

and this is the template for the Semantic UI card I'm trying to create for each pass through the JSON data. This is just standard HTML and is outside the AJAX call:

```
<div class="ui card">
   <div class="image">
      <img src="myimage.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Schedule Title</a>
      <div class="meta">
         <span class="date">Schedule Platform</span>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
         Schedule Description
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="extra content">
      Schedule Date
   </div>
   <div class="extra content">
      <span class="left floated like"><i class="like icon"></i>Like</span>
      <span class="right floated star"><i class="star icon"></i>Favorite</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

I've tried something similar to the below inside the `map()` function of the `success()` function (not an exact representation of the HTML above, but should illustrate the approach), but it isn't working

```
$('.schedule-data')
    .append(`<div class="ui card">`)
    .append(`<div class="image">`)
    .append(`<img src='${item.image}'>`)
    .append(`</div>`)
    .append(`<div class="content">`)
    .append(`<div class="header">${item.title}</div>`)
    .append(`<div class="meta">`)
    .append(`<a>${item.platform}</a>`)
    .append(`</div>`)
    .append(`<div class="description">`)
    .append(`${item.description}`)
    .append(`</div>`)
    .append(`</div>`)
    .append(`<div class="extra content">`)
    .append(`${item.date}`)
    .append(`</div>`)
    .append(`</div>`);
});
```

Am I taking the appropriate approach here and why aren't the elements being styled? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Let's first see how the `JSON` files comes from the server. I think you could also append it all at once instead of this. But please show the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have elements or an array of elements like this (This will work depending on how the `JSON` data you receive is structured):

```
var myData = {
    'image': 'myImage',
    'title': 'This is the title',
    'platform': 'Some platform',
    'description': 'The description',
    'date': '2018-5-14'
}
```

You could create a function to substitute the variable properties and then perform the `append()` operation:

```
function fillData(item) {
    return `<div class='ui card'>
    <div class='image'>
       <img src='${item.image}'>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
       <a class='header'>${item.title}</a>
       <div class='meta'>
          <span class='date'> <a> ${item.platform} </a> </span>
       </div>
       <div class='description'>
         ${item.description}
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class='extra content'>
         ${item.date}
    </div>
    <div class='extra content'>
       <span class='left floated like'><i class='like icon'></i>Like</span>
       <span class='right floated star'><i class='star icon'></i>Favorite</span>
    </div>
 </div>`
}
```

Then inside the `success()` method:

```
let $scheduledata = $('.schedule-data');
$scheduledata.append(`<div class="ui link cards"></div>`);
let $cards = $scheduledata.find('.ui.link.cards')
let newelemarray = data.map(item => fillData(item));
for(let i = 0; i < newelemarray.length; i++){
    $cards.append(newelemarray[i]);
}
```

Comment: This works very well, thank you.  Using the `find()` function was something I hadn't done on my previous attempts, so maybe that was the ticket.

Comment: I am glad to know it works. Thanks for letting me know